# 'WiFi is not connecting' or 'WiFi is not getting connected'?

Tags: grammaticality

Suppose I want to use internet on my phone via WiFi. I turn on Wifi in my phone. But phone is not getting connected to WiFi. So, I just want to tell this to my friend. Which one of the are following are correct to say?

1. WiFi is not connecting.
2. WiFi is not getting connected.
3. WiFi is not being connected.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you may want to add something to the question. For example, what is your take on that or what do you think about those sentences.

Comment: I am confused. I think second one is correct. but I am not sure

Comment: Why do you think 1 and 3 are wrong?

Comment: For first: Because WiFi is not agent here. i think we can use 'connect' when somebody connect something. e.g. I am connecting PC with charger. and third one is also correct. But I have never heard that.

Comment: Apart from the fact that "connect" is both transitive and intransitive verb,  devices are usually connecting to a WiFi network. for example, "I cannot connect to the WiFi (network)" or "my phone is not connecting to the WiFi (network)".

Comment: There is some advice in [this answer on meta](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/465/) on how to write questions that will be well-received by the community. Mostly, people like to see more detail in questions so they can understand why someone might be having trouble with a phrase or word and write a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably put a determiner in front of *WiFi*, such as *my* or *the*. And of the three forms, only the first one sounds natural to my native ear. So, I'd say:

> My WiFi is not connecting.

or:

> The WiFi is not connecting.

But there are probably several other wordings that could be used to say the same thing in a natural way:

> I'm having trouble getting a good WiFi connection.

Since WiFi hotspots are relatively new (at least in comparison to the English language), there's not a lot of precedent for how to use the word *WiFi* in sentences like these. I looks to me like the word is only recently shedding its hyphen; an all lower-case *wifi* may be next.

Comment: I appreciate the accepted answer, but you should really [read this](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer). If someone comes along and leaves a better answer, don't be afraid to change it.